# Testing matplotlib-based plots in Travis CI

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, travis-ci

I have a package that has a module that helps users generate specific plots using matplotlib. When I call these functions in my unit tests inside Travis, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Invalid DISPLAY variable
```

How do I fix that?

After generating the plot, my functions usually call `pyplot.show()`, which opens a window that needs to be closed. When I call these functions in my unit tests inside Travis, they get hung up forever.

How do I test that these plots are being generated using Travis CI?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update:** as per @matt-pitkin comment, the method has been updated. In case an Ubuntu Xenial container is used, the preferred method to enable xvfb is through a Travis service:

```
services:
- xvfb
```

However, if an Ubuntu Trusty container is used, my original answer (below) remains relevant. I also recommend reading the answer by @david-ketcheson, which has a more specific solution to the original question.

---

In order to set the DISPLAY variable inside Travis, you need to emulate a display from inside their VM. [They teach how to do it](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/) using `xvfb`by adding the following to the `before_script` of yout `.travis.yml` file:

```
before_script: # configure a headless display to test plot generation
- "export DISPLAY=:99.0"
- "sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start"
- sleep 3 # give xvfb some time to start
```

In order for Travis not to get hung up on the plots, simply don't call `pyplot.show()`. If you are testing too many plots, make sure to call `pyplot.close()` or it will complain about having too many open images.

Comment: This works! FYI if you're also using [tox](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tox), don't forget to to add `DISPLAY` to `passenv`

Comment: It seems that this now fails, but the alternative option of setting `services: - xvfb` as shown [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/#using-services-xvfb) seem to work.

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this without explicitly setting display by using the "agg" backend in matplotlib.  This is necessary anyway, in my experience, in order to ensure consistency of the generated images.  Just make sure you

```
 matplotlib.use('agg')
```

before you import pyplot or pylab.  I've explained more [here](http://www.davidketcheson.info/2015/01/13/using_matplotlib_image_comparison.html).

Comment: Another option is to set a special environment variable: `export MPLBACKEND=Agg` (https://matplotlib.org/faq/environment_variables_faq.html)

Comment: This is a great solution. I believe setting the env variable is simpler, as it can be done in .travis.yml `before_install` section and doesn't change the code of the package.